# Suunto GPS Watch USB problem

Tags: usb

newbie to linux here.  I see there are other "same type" questions and I hope someone kindly helps me out.  I do not know enough to convert other posts to a solution for myself.  I have a Suunto Ambit GPS watch and I am running Ubuntu 13.04.  The usb device is not showing up.  I see from some other posts you want a dmesg.  Here it is:

```
usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-1: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 1 but max is 0
usb 3-1: config 1 has no interface number 0
usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1493, idProduct=0010
usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 3-1: Product: Ambit
usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Suunto
usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 18B79A4617002000
```

I believe Line two is the issue.  I am using vituralbox and windows client to run the movescount software.  I just converted over to Linux, so I really do not want to have to go back to windows, just for support for my watch...

Comment: have you contact suunto for their read of the problem?

Comment: I've a Suunto Ambit Peak 3 and OpenAmbit doesn't work and the development for Ambit 3 are not planned. On movescount, there is a [Linux User Group](http://www.movescount.com/fr/groups/group5135-Linux_User_Group). May be you can subscribe to push Suunto develop MoveLink for Linux or/and write to Suunto (support@suunto.com) asking them to make a Moveslink portage on linux or support the OpenAmbit project to improve and achieve the support of Suunto Ambit 3. Hope this makes Suunto react.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it's usually best to look up the device by its usb ID (which you can find with `lsusb`. Searching the web for this ID will give you better technical information about the protocol the usb device uses.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use moveslink (windows software) to extract moves from clock you might give OpenAmbit a try. I use it in OpenSuse (instead of moveslink) and transfer moves to MovesCount service via it.
More information from OpenAmbit site: https://sourceforge.net/projects/openambit/

Answer (score 0):

When first connected, this may appear as a USB storage device. *This is typical Windows-device behaviour, and allows the device to auto-load a (Windows) driver.*

Ubuntu does not support or need this type of 'unsafe binary' approach to NEW devices. Instead you may need to use USB mode-switch, to get back to full interface with the device.

Start by checking the output from **`lsusb`**, directly after connecting (anf again after 10-20 seconds.

PS. There does not appear to be anything useful in a Google search for: **1493 0010**  (This may not be the USB ID to look for.)

---

That said, this may be pointless anyway. If the manufacturer only provides for a Windows (or possibly Mac) based application to talk to this device, you need to be running that software (under Wine/Linux, or Windows).

Try the manufacturers forum:

[Customer Q&A, for Suunto Ambit (Black)](http://answers.suunto.com/answers/7064-en_gb/product/SS018374000/suunto-ambit-black-questions-answers/questions.htm?page=8&sort=recentq&dir=asc)

Comment: Or you could use wireshark or similar to figure out the protocol they use to connect the device :)